# Converting JSON file into a suitable string issue with Python

Tags: python, json, parsing, aws-sdk, iot

I have a JSON file as follows :

```
{  
   "desired":{
        "property1":{  
          "port":"/dev/usbserial",
          "rx":{  
             "watchdoginterval":3600
          },
          "state":{  
             "path":"/Users/user1"
          },
          "enabled":"true",
          "active":{
             "enabled":"true"
          }
       },
       "property2":{  
          "signal_interrupt":"USR2",
          "signal_description_path":"/tmp/logger.log"
       },
       "property3":{  
          "periodmins":40
       },
   }
}
```

I am having issues trying to convert this into a string for use with AWS IoT. The function I am using is `deviceShadowHandler.shadowUpdate(JSONPayload, customShadowCallback_Update, 5)`

Where JSONPayload should be the JSON string.

I have tried :

```
with open('JSONfile.json' , 'r') as f:
    dict = json.load(f)

JSONPayload = str(dict)
```

but I receive an "Invalid JSON file error".

An attempt to manually create a literal string from the jSON file gets messy with complaints about "EOL while scanning string literal" etc.

What is the best solution to solve this? I am new to JSON and stuff and Python.

Comment: You have a trailing comma on your last item in the JSON file - remove it and you're good to go!

Comment: btw, json is already a string, so there should be no need to convert it to a `dict` (don't use `dict` as a variable name!) and then back to a string.

Comment: @rgk Ok thanks. However it still states an invalid json file when i remove it

Comment: @quamrana so I can just convert directly from the file to a string?

Comment: Here's a link for a second opinion: https://jsonlint.com/

Comment: Having opened the file as `f`. it should be `JSONPayload = f.read()`

Answer (score 0):

[Trailing commas are not allowed in JSON](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Trailing_commas#Trailing_commas_in_JSON).

```
{  
  "desired":{
    "property1":{  
      "port":"/dev/usbserial",
      "rx":{  
       "watchdoginterval":3600
      },
      "state":{  
       "path":"/Users/user1"
      },
      "enabled":"true",
      "active":{
       "enabled":"true"
      }
    },
    "property2":{  
      "signal_interrupt":"USR2",
      "signal_description_path":"/tmp/logger.log"
    },
    "property3":{  
      "periodmins":40
    } # <- no comma there
  }
}
```